# Compare and merge fields in two CSV files

Tags: python, csv, merge

I'm a beginner in python and I'm trying to compare two fields (timestamps) in two csv files and if they match merge them in a third file. Input files look like:

file1:

```
name,time,operation
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:22.333662984Z,INSERT
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:24.334536781Z,INSERT
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:27.339662984Z,READ
```

file2:

```
name,time,host,instance,type,type_instance,value
cpu_value,2015-10-06T15:07:22.333662984Z,vm1-VirtualBox,0,cpu,user,24874
cpu_value,2015-10-06T15:07:24.334536781Z,vm1-VirtualBox,0,cpu,nice,592
cpu_value,2015-10-06T15:07:27.339662984Z,vm1-VirtualBox,0,cpu,system,2932
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import csv

with open('f1.csv', 'rb') as f1, open ('f2.csv', 'rb') as f2:
    next(f1) #skip line 1
    next(f2) #skip line 1
    reader1 = csv.reader(f1)
    reader2 = csv.reader(f2)
    for row1 in reader1:
            for row2 in reader2:
                    if row1[1] == row2[1]:
                            data = [row1[0],row2[0]]
                            print data
```

Then, I got this error:

```
['cpu_value', 'Cassandra']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "merger.py", line 10, in <module>
if row1[1] == row2[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Update**

Expected output:

```
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:22.333662984Z,INSERT,cpu_value,vm1-VirtualBox,0,cpu,user,24874
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:24.334536781Z,INSERT,cpu_value,vm1-VirtualBox,0,cpu,nice,592
Cassandra,2015-10-06T15:07:27.339662984Z,READ,cpu_value,vm1-VirtualBox,0,cpu,nice,592
```

You can access the files through this [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01394724335350554441). Please let me know if you any idea. Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @AerofoilKite I updated the post.

Comment: Is it possible one of those csv files has a seemingly empty line OR a line with just not enough fields? That's what the error message is hinting at. If you don't know, you should consider adding a link to both files so that others may inspect them.

Comment: Are you sure you *don't* want to interpolate time? For example, if the closest match is `cassandra,01:01:00.000123` and `cpu,01:01:00.000175` do you really want  to output nothing?

Comment: @qarma thanks for your suggestion. This is what exactly I'm looking. Because the timestamps wouldn't be identical at all. So I need to interpolate the time.

Comment: @qarma would you give me a hint?

Comment: Use `bisect` over sorted array to find nearest match; Decide on heuristic for missing data (e.g. >1s is too far).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can make the assumption that all timestamps are unique and that they will match exactly (that is, no interpolation is needed), then we can start out by reading the first file into a dictionary, where the keys are timestamps and the values are CSV lines.

Then, we read the second file, and for each CSV line, look up in the dictionary. If there is a matching line, we can print it, or store it, or whatever. Furthermore, we use `pop` to remove the matching line, so that we can easily find the unmatched lines in the end!

The following code should give the desired output for your test data of 2*3 lines.

```
import csv

matches = []
unmatched1 = []
unmatched2 = []
f1_dict = {}

with open('f1.csv', 'r') as f1:
    next(f1)  # skip line 1
    reader1 = csv.reader(f1)
    for row1 in reader1:
        f1_dict[row1[1]] = row1

with open('f2.csv', 'r') as f2:
    next(f2)  # skip line 1
    reader2 = csv.reader(f2)
    for row2 in reader2:
        row1 = f1_dict.pop(row2[1], None)
        if row1 is None:
            unmatched2.append(row2)
        else:
            matches.append((row1, row2))

unmatched1 = list(f1_dict.values())
for row1, row2 in matches:
    output_row = row1 + [row2[0]] + row2[2:]
    print(','.join(output_row))  # or use csv.writer
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated the post with access link to the data.

Comment: How about multiple row in a particular time?
Your map can handle that

Comment: @AerofoilKite: No, it cannot handle that -- it works only if we assume that timestamps are unique (no two identical timestamps in the same file), and that they match exactly across the two files (no interpolation needed)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use pandas DataFrame : [pandas package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.16.2/)

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

L1 = pd.read_csv('f1.csv')
L2 = pd.read_csv('f2.csv')

result = pd.merge(L1, L2, on='time')

for row in result.values:
    print row
```

Output:

```
['Cassandra' '2015-10-06T15:07:22.333662984Z' 'INSERT' 'cpu_value' 'vm1-VirtualBox' 0L 'cpu' 'user' 24874L]
['Cassandra' '2015-10-06T15:07:24.334536781Z' 'INSERT' 'cpu_value' 'vm1-VirtualBox' 0L 'cpu' 'nice' 592L]
['Cassandra' '2015-10-06T15:07:27.339662984Z' 'READ' 'cpu_value' 'vm1-VirtualBox' 0L 'cpu' 'system' 2932L]
```

For more: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

L1 = []
L2 = []

with open('f1.csv', 'rb') as f1, open ('f2.csv', 'rb') as f2:
    next(f1) #skip line 1
    next(f2) #skip line 1
    reader1 = csv.reader(f1)
    reader2 = csv.reader(f2)

    for row in reader1:
        L1.append(row)

    for row in reader2:
        L2.append(row)


for row1 in L1:
    for row2 in L2:
        if row1[1] == row2[1]:
            data = row1+[row2[0]]+row[2:]
            print data
```

Output:

```
['Cassandra', '2015-10-06T15:07:22.333662984Z', 'INSERT', 'cpu_value', 'vm1-VirtualBox', '0', 'cpu', 'system', '2932']
['Cassandra', '2015-10-06T15:07:24.334536781Z', 'INSERT', 'cpu_value', 'vm1-VirtualBox', '0', 'cpu', 'system', '2932']
['Cassandra', '2015-10-06T15:07:27.339662984Z', 'READ', 'cpu_value', 'vm1-VirtualBox', '0', 'cpu', 'system', '2932']
```

You can try pandas DataFrame too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33244071/1924666

Comment: How about merge sort for something more formal?